# Javascript how do sum class numeric value?

Tags: simplecart

my question is class have number value how do fix this???

```
<span class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></span>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = $('.simpleCart_grandTotal').text();
var y = 2;
var z = x * y;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
</script>
```

the output `<span class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></span>` is $10
this multiplied by 2 result will show `<p id="demo"></p>` is $20 and how do use this $ sign remove from first class and put second class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var x = $('.simpleCart_grandTotal').text();
>
> var intX = Number(x.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,""));
>
> var y = 2;
>
> var z = "$" + (intX * y);
>
> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;